# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' when running SQLTools in VScode

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, sqltools

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[Error - 2:45:20 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
```

I've updated VScode, SQLTools, and NodeJS and keep receiving this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.